# How do we get string values from javascript object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have javascript objects like:

```
{["186,2017"]}
```

I would like to only have:

```
186, 2017
```

I tried (**thougth i had a json**):

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

But that is what gives me the json and not the string values only,

This is how I get the whoel thing:

```
$("#years").slider({
      tooltip: 'always',
      tooltip_position:'left',
      formatter: function(value) {
        currentRange = value instanceof Array ? value.join('-'): value;
        return 'Years: ' + (value instanceof Array ? value.join('-'): value);
        console.log(value instanceof Array ? value.join(', '): value);
      }
    });

    getData = function() {
      var data = {
          years: $('#years').slider().val().split(', ')
      }  
      console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    }

    $("#years").on("slide", function(slideEvt) {
      getData();
    });
```

Comment: `{["186,2017"]}` is not valid JSON - if the JSON is `["186,2017"]` ... `JSON.parse(json).map(Number)` - though, that would result in `[186,2017]` ... because you still have an array ... so, perhaps ... `JSON.parse(json).join(", ")` - in the above , json is the JSON string that "you have" ... if what you have is an array, `data` .. then you just want `data.join(', ')`

Comment: @JaromandaX I have updated the question, that format is what I get when I use stringify

Comment: right, so you **don't have JSON at all** you have data = `{years: ["186", "2017"]}`

Comment: @JaromandaX actually yes... thought that was a json tho

Comment: you still don't have JSON ... JSON would be a **string**

Comment: So why not `data["years"][0] + ", " + data["years"][1]`?

Comment: no, you do not have any JSON in that code - it's a javascript object

Comment: @Sraw oh well.. that's an answer, and it works. Pleas einsert it and i'll accept it, also updating the quetsion title

Comment: @JaromandaX updating the question title, you're correct

Comment: if you want `"186, 2017"` from data with a value `{years: ["186", "2017"]}` - then it's `data.years.join(', ')`

Comment: @JaromandaX beautiful, could you place that into an answer pls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gather the object you are dealing with is a variable called `data` with the content `{years: ["186", "2017"]}`

to "get" the value `"186, 2017"` from that data

```
data.years.join(", ");
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let obj = { years: ["186", "2017"] }

console.log(...obj.years);
```

You can try to spread it as above

Comment: but that won't split the elements by `", "` just `","` :p